# How to capture voice and/or transcript from microsoft teams meeting?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to get either a recording or text transcript of a Microsoft Teams meeting?

I have investigated an option to add a bot to do this as for example here, it is mentioned that this should be possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts

Here https://dev.botframework.com/ it is implied that it is possible to "Create a bot with the ability to speak, listen, understand, and learn from your users with Azure Cognitive Services" with Microsoft Bot Framework.

However, the nodejs samples don't seem to contain anything related to communicating via voice: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs

Any hints how to obtain either voice recording or text transcript via bot or a different  approach? I prefer to use nodejs or python since not familiar with c#.

Comment: You can use [Get Call API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to retrieve the transcriptionInfo from meeting. Recorded calls stored in stream you can fetch it using [Get Call record API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-callrecord?view=graph-rest-1.0). You will require a call Id which will be generated once your call is completed

Comment: Refer to [updateRecordingstatus](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/record-calls-and-meetings-the-updaterecordingstatus-api-in-microsoft-graph-is-now-generally-available/) API which allows bots to record Microsoft Teams calls and meetings as part of their policy-based recording solution.

Comment: Hi @jjei, Did you get the approach to getting a text transcript via a bot?